# Dynamically change image src using Jquery not working in IE and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing a captcha for a email. when click on `linkEmail` button email modal will open.
there i have to set captcha image generated by a handler (CaptchaGenerator.ashx) on click of `linkEmail` button click. Here is the code for that.

```
$(".linkEmail").click(function () {
  //Load captcha image
  $('.imgCaptcha').attr('src', '/Custom/AppCode/Utilities/CaptchaGenerator.ashx');
  $('#emailModal').modal();
});
```

Above code is working fine in crome but **not working** in IE and firefox.
Although i have tried followings there is no luck.

HTML:

```
<p id="captchacontainerp" class="captchacontainer"></p>
-------------------------------------------------------------
$('#captchacontainerp').prepend($("<img id='imCaptcha' class='imgCaptcha' src='/Custom/AppCode/Utilities/CaptchaGenerator.ashx'></img>"));
-------------------------------------------------------------
var img = $('<img id="imCaptcha" class="imgCaptcha">');
img.attr('src', '/Custom/AppCode/Utilities/CaptchaGenerator.ashx');
$('#captchacontainerp').empty();
img.appendTo('#captchacontainerp');
---------------------------------------------------------------
$('#captchacontainerp').empty();
$('#captchacontainerp').append($("<img id='imCaptcha' class='imgCaptcha' src='/Custom/AppCode/Utilities/CaptchaGenerator.ashx'></img>"));
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ghwYF/ working fine for me (after hitting run, or else you get 404 for that image)

Comment: try the ajax call as i did in my answer resolve your issue..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IE caching all GET request, so add a timestamp to your request URL e.g :

```
$(".linkEmail").click(function () {
   //Load captcha image
   $('.imgCaptcha').attr('src', '/Custom/AppCode/Utilities/CaptchaGenerator.ashx?'+new Date().getTime());
   $('#emailModal').modal();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. i tried everything like                               
`Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
 Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now);
 Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
 Response.Cache.SetNoStore();`                                   not worked for me. But this simple code done the magic

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the src attribute to '' before changing it again?
Also, what are the caching settings you are using (both locally, and on the server)

Comment: changing the `src` attribute to '' will result in a request to the current page, don't do that

Answer (score 0):

If you specify any inline style attribute, Height or Width like,

```
<img src="themes/images/01.png" height="100" width="100" />
<img src="themes/images/01.png" style="height:100px; width=100px;" />
```

> then first remove it and try again.

Even if you externally specify style using style tag,

```
  #imageId{
    height : 100px;
    width : 100px;
  }
```

then also first remove it and try.
After you remove the style attribute from the images, it will display image.

Height attribute is may work with IE but width attribute not working.

If the above solution doesn't work, then : 
     Sometime PNG files are not displaying as well. So try to use their JPG image.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to call re captcha button.
After some searching, now  function works fine in almost all the famous browsers(chrome,Firefox,IE,Edge,...):

```
function recaptcha(theUrl) {
  $.get(theUrl, function(data, status){});
  document.getElementById("captcha-img").src = "";
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("captcha-img").src = "captcha?"+new Date().getTime();
  }, 0);
}
```

'theUrl' is used to render new captcha image and can be ignored in your case. The most important point is generating new URL which forces FF and IE to rerender the image.