# img.src won't work with Firefox, but Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to create a small captcha to learn JavaScript. I'm using PHP to create the captcha image, refreshing the image, clearing box, changing colors of form are done by JavaScript.

My problem is starting at refreshing that PHP generated image. I've written the code using the 'src' attribute, but it doesn't work with Firefox. I just could test with Chrome (I'm currently on linux and can't access a windows computer), it works.

On Firefox, I've tried with a static image. With static image, it works on Firefox also.

My PHP code works perfectly (also it's not a issue about client-side) so there is my JavaScript code that refreshes the image:

```
function cpt_refreshCaptcha() {

            document.getElementById("cpt_theImage").src = cpt_path + "cpt_interface.php?p=img";
            console.log("src = " + document.getElementById("cpt_theImage").src);
            cpt_resetBox();

    }
```

I also checked the `cpt_path + "cpt_interface.php?p=img` part, it seems to be correct.

What is my problem with Firefox?

Comment: The browser is probably just caching the image. You could add a nonce parameter, or make sure the server is setting the proper headers to tell the browser not to cache the response.

Comment: Yes, it's about caching! Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a problem with the cache. Try to disable the cache of the firefox browser. If that's the problem you can add a timestamp after the file's name. 
Check this for more info: [Dynamically change image src using Jquery not working in IE and firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155480/dynamically-change-image-src-using-jquery-not-working-in-ie-and-firefox)

Comment: Yes, it's about caching, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try appending a random string at the end to avoid caching issues:

```
var rand = Math.random() + new Date().getTime();
document.getElementById("cpt_theImage").src = cpt_path + "cpt_interface.php?p=img&rand=" + rand;
```