# Changing image source not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, typescript, firefox, html2canvas

I want to change the image when the user captures the page using `html2canvas`.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7t3z4yfo/1/

I change the image using `img.src = newImageLink` as shown in this code.

```
const newImageLink = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575936123452-b67c3203c357?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aW1hZ2V8ZW58MHx8MHx8fDA%3D&w=1000&q=80"

html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture"), {
    allowTaint: true,
  onclone: function (doc, el) {
    const images = doc.querySelectorAll('img')
    images.forEach(img => {
        img.src = newImageLink
    })
  }
}).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
});
```

The image is changed in Chrome browser, but not in Firefox.

Someone says it's the Firefox caching issue, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14155514/12765965).

I have tried to add `?${Date.now()}` to the end of the new image source, but it does not work.

Could you tell me how to change the image source in Firefox?